# How to manually reload Google Map with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this piece of code within a Bootstrap template. I am facing issues when loading images within a Bootstrap Tab content pane.

This is the JavaScript code which I use to initialize the Map:

```js
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50, 50);

var myOptions = {
    zoom: _zoom,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    }
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Google Office!'
});
```

I have not found any method(s) on the internet to manually reload a Google Map instance.

Is this possible and how? Thanks!

Answer (score 131):

Yes, you can 'refresh' a Google Map like this:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

This basically sends a signal to your map to redraw it.

Comment: Does this work when you are using iframes from Google? Where would I put this code?

Comment: Argh! Or so I thought... that is, there are some caveats. It doesn't seem to work at all in Chrome but it does in Firefox, which is... weird. Also, triggering `resize` will re-position the div fairly well, but it's still a few pixels off in my case, until manually resized.

Answer (score 4):

```
map.setZoom(map.getZoom());
```

For some reasons, `resize` trigger did not work for me, and this one worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can refresh with this:

```
map.panBy(0, 0);
```

Comment: it doesn't reload anything