# Google Map doesn't fully expand when using Toggle

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps-api-3, toggle, expand

I have two divs positioned next to each other. The one on the left contains a Google Map while the one on the right is empty, which I am using as a sidebar. I created a toggle button that collapses the sidebar and expands the map to cover the full width of the viewport. However, the Google Map div doesn't seem to expand fully and always leaves part of the space empty. This issue doesn't occur when I'm just expanding a plain div so I wonder if it's a problem with Google Maps? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XnDsS/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
       $("#side_bar").animate({
           width: 'toggle'
       });
       var value = $("#map")[0].style.width !== "100vw" ? '100vw' : '80vw';
       $("#map").animate({
           width: value
       });
    });
});
```

I get the same problem on all browsers, latest versions:

[Image Example](http://oi57.tinypic.com/2heek9l.jpg)

Comment: in your fiddle the map resizes perfect here. could you post some screenshots? ant post your browser info

Comment: @LGVentura I added a link to a screenshot on the OP. I get the same issue regardless of which browser I'm using. If you increase the Fiddle Result width, the same thing happens there. I uploaded an example on the following site: [Website Example](http://www.dogeglobal.com/toggle.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resize your map while animate your `#map` width using `step:function(){}` callback of `.animate()`. Take a look:

```
$("#map").animate({
    width:value
    },{step:function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
    },
});
```

I updated your fiddle as demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/XnDsS/1/

Comment: Works fine now, thanks! Can I ask what is the difference between step:function and function? Tried it with both and I seem to get the same result.

Comment: @user3716388 step:function() is a callback of .animate() function. When you animate some element you can call a function when the animation start, end, done, fail, progress. read more about .animate() http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the part of the map that is grey just is not loaded yet. If you pane over to it, it loads properly.

Try refreshing google maps after you toggle:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

[(thanks to this answer for the google maps refresh script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264989/how-to-manually-reload-google-map-with-javascript)