# Show Google Map In Modal After Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

so I'm working on a site where I want to show a google map inside a modal after an ajax call. I'm using bootstrap to show a modal, the problem is the map just stays blank after the modal is opened.

Something weird that happens is when I hit `f12` on chrome to bring up the developer tab the map magically shows up although not centered on the marker position.

This is my Ajax Call:

```
$('.btnSeeOrder').on("click", function(){
    $("#modalSeeOrder").modal("show"); //open bootstrap modal
    var order_id = $(this).attr("data-orderId");

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "get_order_details.php",
      data: {
        order_id: order_id
      },
      beforeSend: function(){
        $(".order-details-modal").html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spinning'></i>");
      },
      success: function(data){
        $(".order-details-modal").html(data);
      },
      error: function(){
        $(".order-details-modal").html("<b>Ooops... Error....</b>");
      }
    });
  });
```

This is my `get_order_details.php` file:

```
<?php
  require '../../../app/Functions.php';
  $obj = new Admin_Functions();

  //Get order info, user info and map
  $info = $obj->getOrderInfo($_POST['order_id']);

?>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom: 25px; padding-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// latitude and longitude are being loaded in from the database 
// example coords from database: 50.44444,-19.444444

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo explode(",", $info["lat_lng"])[0]; ?>,<?php echo explode(",", $info["lat_lng"])[1]; ?>);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 16,
  center: myLatlng,
  styles:
  [{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#e9e5dc"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"color":"#545454"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"-87"},{"lightness":"-40"},{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway.controlled_access","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#f0f0f0"},{"saturation":"-22"},{"lightness":"-16"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway.controlled_access","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway.controlled_access","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"-52"},{"hue":"#00e4ff"},{"lightness":"-16"}]}]
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  icon: 'https://www.robotevents.com/images/maps/markers/orange.png'
});
</script>
```

This is what the map looks like when loaded in:
[image]

Anyone know how I can fix or go about this issue? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: i guess the console is blank?

Comment: Yeah, the console is blank. No errors show up. @techLove

Comment: It looks like it is not initialized. i would suggest to try: put google map code in a function and call it in : success: function(data){
        $(".order-details-modal").html(data); newfunc();
      },

Comment: Ok, I just tried it and the map still show up blank. :/ @techLove

Comment: is modal autoopen : false ??

Comment: Yeah, it's closed by default until the button is clicked.

Comment: I had the same issue. As I know, google map need to reinit after showing modal

Comment: How do yo reinit @spiil?

Comment: add new function like: done: function(){ newfunc(); },

Comment: @BrianMoreno [You can do it like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17289420/3758361)

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated! Found the solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so as some of the comments said and investigating a bit more I have found the solution. I added some javascript code in my `get_order_details.php` file after the `var marker = google....` to redraw and center my map after the modal has been opened:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

    // Recenter the map now that it's been redrawn
    var reCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo explode(",", $info["lat_lng"])[0]; ?>,<?php echo explode(",", $info["lat_lng"])[1]; ?>);
    map.setCenter(reCenter);
  });
```

So the whole javascript inside `get_order_details.php` ended up looking like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Show google map
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo explode(",", $info[0]["lat_lng"])[0]; ?>,<?php echo explode(",", $info[0]["lat_lng"])[1]; ?>);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: myLatlng,
    styles:
    [{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#e9e5dc"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"color":"#545454"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"-87"},{"lightness":"-40"},{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway.controlled_access","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#f0f0f0"},{"saturation":"-22"},{"lightness":"-16"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway.controlled_access","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway.controlled_access","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"-52"},{"hue":"#00e4ff"},{"lightness":"-16"}]}]
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    icon: 'https://www.robotevents.com/images/maps/markers/orange.png'
  });

  //Redraw and center map
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

    // Recenter the map now that it's been redrawn
    var reCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo explode(",", $info["lat_lng"])[0]; ?>,<?php echo explode(",", $info["lat_lng"])[1]; ?>);
    map.setCenter(reCenter);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying add this in your CSS class

```
._gmaps_cdv_{
    background-color: transparent !;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Or verify if you put in your script tag for google maps attr async

Comment: Do I give these attributes directly to the #map-canvas?

Answer (score 0):

- Here your Map is not loading due to the imitate call of the ajax the main reason for partial loading of map try to load the map after ajax call.
- Instead of dynamic loading of Google Maps API you could utilize 
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  were:
  function initialize(){ //Map initialization code};